# Get Selected Index of List View From Page Resource

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Below is my XAML code, I want to get the list selection index from the ListView using SelectionChanged event. I cannot achieve this.

```
<Page
    x:Class="MMRevamp_2016.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MMRevamp_2016"
    xmlns:ViewModels="using:MMRevamp_2016.ViewModels"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="Gray"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <ViewModels:HomePageViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="headerTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="16"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="pivotTemplate">
            <ListView x:Name="listView" Background="White" SelectionChanged="getIndex" ItemsSource="{Binding Articles}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-25 0 -25 0">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Tapped="ArticleDetailStackPanel_Tapped">
                            <Grid>
                                <Image x:Name="ArticleImage" Source="{Binding ImageURL}"></Image>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Border VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="65" Background="Black" Opacity="0.5">
                                    </Border>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="HeadLine" Text="{Binding HeadLine}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                                               Margin="10 0 0 5" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                               FontSize="20" Foreground="White"
                                               Pivot.SlideInAnimationGroup="GroupTwo"
                                               FontWeight="Bold" />                                    
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Abstract}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="15"
                                   Pivot.SlideInAnimationGroup="GroupTwo" Margin="10 5 0 10"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="Gray">
        <Grid x:Name="LoadingGrid" Visibility="Visible">
            <ProgressRing x:Name="progressRing" IsActive="True" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="60"
                          Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 20 0 0"></ProgressRing>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="45"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Image Source="Source" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="1 5 0 0"></Image>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                    <Button x:Name="HamburgerButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;"
                            Width="60" Height="60" Background="Transparent" Margin="-10 -20 0 0" 
                            Click="HamburgerButton_Click"/>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="செய்திகள்" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" 
                           Margin="-35 0 0 0" Foreground="White"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Row="2" x:Name="ArticlesGrid" Visibility="Collapsed">
                <SplitView x:Name="MySplitView" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" IsPaneOpen="False" 
               CompactPaneLength="0" OpenPaneLength="220">
                    <SplitView.Pane>
                        <ListView x:Name="menuBindList" Background="Gray">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Tag="{Binding SectionName}">
                                            <!--<Button x:Name="MenuButton1" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE825;"
                                  Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" Margin="-10 0 0 0"/>-->
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TitleofAccess}"
                                                   Tag="{Binding SectionName}" FontSize="18" 
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" Tapped="MenuTextBlock_Tapped" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </SplitView.Pane>
                    <SplitView.Content>
                        <ScrollViewer Name="articlesScroll">
                            <Pivot DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}" x:Name="pivot" 
                                    HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource headerTemplate}" 
                                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource pivotTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Feeds}" Margin="0,-10,0,10"
                                    SelectionChanged="pivot_SelectionChanged">
                            </Pivot>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </SplitView.Content>
                </SplitView>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>        
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

If anyone guide me to achieve this would be very helpful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the getIndex method do this,

int selectedItemIndex = (sender as ListView).SelectedIndex;